# How to Password Protect Sunspot Solr Server Admin Pages in an Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

How can i protect the solr admin pages using a password?

I'm using :

sunspot_rails (2.1.1)
sunspot_solr (2.1.1)

Application Setup :

Rails 3.2.12
ruby 2.0.0p598

Comment: How does your User Model work? If you use [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) you could simple put a `before_filter :authenticate_admin!` inside your solr controller.

Comment: @TheF I'm guessing you haven't used sunspot-solr yet. Solr runs independently on a separate port.